# How to solve Configuration with name 'default' not found error in Android Studio - andraskindler quickscroll

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to add andraskindler quickscroll library https://github.com/andraskindler/quickscroll to Android Studio. I have downloaded the zip and copied the QuickScroll directory to the Android studio project under a projects directory

```
- My Project
- app
- libraries
   -> QuickScroll
```

I have added the library to settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:QuickScroll'
```

And to the build.gradle under `app`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:QuickScroll')
}
```

However, I get a message when I try and rebuild

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Comment: This confusing error message is indicating that it can't find the "app" project in your build. You don't show it in the directory structure; where did it go?

Comment: @ScottBarta Sorry, the app directory is there, I have updated the post to reflect that. I think the error message about 'app' is just due to the failed gradle project sync failed.

Comment: The error message is exactly what's relevant -- it's the same thing that's causing the sync failure. The error message in general means that it can't find the project "app" where it's looking for it. So either your app directory is missing a build.gradle file or there's some serious problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.andraskindler.quickscroll:quickscroll:0.9.8'
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It would be better to describe a bit more about your suggestion

Comment: Your welcome, add this dependency to your gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue.. Check out:

1. **Automatically download from repository:**
   You can go with `F12` and add it in dependencies as `1.Library Depencency` which downloads lib from repository and add automatically proper settings.
2. **Add as module:**
   Go the same with `F12` to `Project Structure` and click green plus to:

   Import Existing Project(ADT or Gradle project as module)

**next,next,finish**. Add this module in `dependencies` of your appilcation module (like in **1.** point).

GL

Comment: F12 doesn't seem to do anything for me. Do I have to first navigate to a certain part of the UI?